# In Auctex, how could I fold acronyms?

Tags: auctex, code-folding

Auctex comes with a folding mode that already folds most of the uninteresting things. However, acronym macros are not folded. How can I instruct Auctex to fold acronym macros (e.g., `\ac`, `\acp`, `\acf`, etc.)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[printonlyused,nolist]{acronym}

% Acronyms
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{IDS}{Intrusion Detection Systems}
  \acro{ML}{Machine Learning}
\end{acronym}

\begin{document}

\title{Just another Auctex document}

\section{Section 1}
This section uses acronyms. For example, \ac{IDS} or \ac{ML}.

\end{document}
```

If I enable folding mode (`TeX-fold-mode`), how could I instruct Auctex to also fold the macros `\ac{}`?

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered the variable "TeX-fold-macro-spec-list". This variable contains a list of macros that are folded by "TeX-fold-mode". To fold the acronym macros (e.g.: \ac{*}, \acp{*}, \acf{*}, \acpf{*}), I have placed the following lines in my init.el file:

```
;; Set custom folds for Acronyms
(add-to-list 'TeX-fold-macro-spec-list '("{1}" ("ac" "acf")))
(add-to-list 'TeX-fold-macro-spec-list '("{1}s" ("acp" "acpf")))
```